# Accept only HTTPS requests in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

For the some actions, I would like to accept only HTTPS request.
This is my first code, but I think there is a better way.

```
before_filter :reject_http_request, :only => [:fucntion_a, :function_b]

def reject_http_request
  scheme = request.protocol.to_s.downcase
  if scheme == 'http://'
    raise AccessDeniedException.new("Not allowed protocol scheme")
  end
  true
end
```

How can I improve this code?

Comment: codereview.stackexchange.com is the appropriate place to ask for code reviews

Comment: I didn't ask to review my code. I asked a better idea or way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this at the Rack level with the [`rack-ssl-enforcer`](https://github.com/tobmatth/rack-ssl-enforcer) gem. It's configurable to allow exclusion of specific paths, hosts, and methods.

If it meets your needs, I'd recommend doing this over rolling your own solution. We currently use it in production and it works great.

Comment: Agreed, Rails shouldn't be handling this. If the request can be turned away at the webserver, you shouldn't let it get all the way to Rails.

Answer (score 7):

For forcing SSL for a **particular action**, you can use [`force_ssl`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ForceSSL/ClassMethods.html#method-i-force_ssl).
For the **entire app**, you can just do: `config.force_ssl = true` in your `environment.rb` file.
Read [more here](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2011/05/configuring-rails-3-https-ssl/).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. However, `config.force_ssl` should be set in application.rb, not environment.rb. (Totally leaving open the possibility that the file might have changed in 7 and a half years.)