# Rails 4 throw error if url is visited not using ask

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, custom-exceptions

I'm building a small API with rails and would like to protect the routes so that if someone attempts to access the api over http it will throw a JSON error response.

Would this something I would setup in the controller or on a route level?

Comment: You don't want authorization in a rails routes.rb, trust me :)

Comment: this? [accept only https requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14190615/accept-only-https-requests-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @preciz that looks good, cheers!